# Canvas doesn't draw currency symbol (like "₴")

Tags: android, canvas

I have one problem. When my view drawing currency symbol in string doesn't drawing.

This is my code:

```
 String s = mCurrencyName + "/" + mOdometerTypeUnitName;
 // s = ₴/км - I can see this in debug or in logs  
 canvas.drawText(s, (float) (mLeftCircleCenterX - mPaint.measureText(mCurrencyName + "/" + mOdometerTypeUnitName) / 2 - mLittleCircleInnerRadius * 0.2),
                mLeftCircleCenterY + mLittleCircleValueTextSize * 0.75f,
                mPaint);
```

But in my device I see **/км** without **₴** sumbol.

Comment: do you have to use canvas? If not, I know, there is easier way to get currency symbols by using Locale. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258511/how-to-get-currency-symbol-by-currency-name/) pls.

Comment: @BurakCakir I want draw currency symbol on canvas. I already have currency symbol (and I use code from your link for getting currency symbol)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Your font (Roboto or the other one) does not support this sign. Try looking [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/design/Roboto_Specimen_Book_20131031.pdf)

Remember, that Roboto font is provided with the phone, so the signs might also differ on different versions of Android.