# Currency Symbol based on the country code

Tags: android, string, currency

I am doing one app in that I have to display the currency symbol in front of the price. I have 6 currency types. But I got the currency symbols of Rupees, dollar, and Euro... Still I want to get to know the currency symbol of GBP, CAD, AUD, SGD.

How can I achieve the currency symbol of this currencies. For rupees, Euro, and dollar I mentioned the value in String and I am concatenating my text view. I want remaining currencies I mentioned above want in the same manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get currency symbol by currency name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258511/how-to-get-currency-symbol-by-currency-name)

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple strings file like ta, en suffix.

use the following string in different language/Country string files

for Indian rupees

```
<string name="currency_symbol">\u20B9</string>
```

for Euro sign

```
<string name="currency_symbol">&#8364;</string>
```

For other signs refer this link, it will help you...

https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/5484121

Comment: I want the values of AUD,SGD, CAD to add as a strings