# Get Currency symbol of only one character (e.g $,₹, etc) (Locale doesn't matter) android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, currency, currency-formatting

i have currency code (e.g. USD,INR,etc...). I want to get symbols of only one letter of those codes (e.g $,₹, etc). i have tried to find many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258511/how-to-get-currency-symbol-by-currency-name) but it doesn't works for me. i am using code as below

```
var pound = Currency.getInstance("GBP");
var symbol = pound.getSymbol();
```

but it returns symbols like (Rs., US$, AU$, etc...). i want to get only one character symbol as mentioned above. i know that symbols are dependent on their locale but i want to get symbols independent from their locale.

Answer (score 3):

try to calling default `Locale` in getSymbol() like  `getSymbol(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY))` check below code

```
Currency pound = Currency.getInstance("GBP");
pound.getSymbol(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY));
```

Comment: This parameter requires Api N so, it only works on naugat or above it. if you have any  other solution then please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question quickly in Kotlin:

```
var pound = Currency.getInstance("GBP");
val symbol = pound.symbol
println(symbol) // prints £
```

In case useful,  I paste my solution to get currency code (i.e.: EUR) and currency symbol (i.e. €) and   :

```
val locale = Locale.getDefault()
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)
println(numberFormat.currency)  // on my device in Italy prints: EUR

val symbol = numberFormat.currency?.symbol
println(symbol) // on my device in Italy prints: €
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
import android.os.Build

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        count()
    }

    fun count () {
        val pound = Currency.getInstance("USD")
        var str:String
        str = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=24) pound.getSymbol(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY))
        else pound.getSymbol(resources.configuration.locale)
        tvText.text = str
    }


}
```

Comment: No. it doen't work. it's returning symbols like US$,CA$,Rs. etc...i want to get $,₹, etc..

Comment: Well, I don't understand why. Code above returns $.

Comment: i think it's Because of your default locale is setted as per your default country settings of your mobile. you can test it out by setting different countries like india, japan,etc

Answer (score 0):

I simply created this kotlin extension function which isolates the currency symbol if there is one or uses the provided symbol if there isn't one.

```java
// Supply the Currency Symbol, e.g. US$, would return $ and IDR would return IDR
fun String.isolateCurrencySymbol(): String{
    for (char in this){
        if (char !in CharRange('A', 'Z')){
            return char.toString()
        }
    }
    return this
}
```