# I just need the local currency symbol in a String depending on the country the user is, in Kotlin for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Is there a simple way for the system to return the local currency symbol?

I been searching but I cant find anything, in swift you can achieve this with two lines:

let locale = Locale.current

let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol!

¿Is there anything similar in Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Currency symbol of only one character (e.g $,₹, etc) (Locale doesn't matter) android kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949902/get-currency-symbol-of-only-one-character-e-g-%e2%82%b9-etc-locale-doesnt-matter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try:

```kotlin
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault())
val symbol = numberFormat.currency?.symbol

// symbol = £
```

Answer (score 1):

In case useful, I paste my solution in Kotlin, for currency symbol (i.e. €) and currency code (i.e.: EUR)  :

```
val locale = Locale.getDefault()
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)
println(numberFormat.currency)  // on my device in Italy prints: EUR

val symbol = numberFormat.currency?.symbol
println(symbol) // on my device in Italy prints: €
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android, it could be an option.

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).currencyCode
```