# Adding a sign to currency

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm using Java NumberFormat for displaying currencies, and i want to add currencies ***signs***, like for:
Hong Kong dollar: HK$
Canadian dollar: CA$
Singapore dollar: S$ ...

***NOT*** the $, £, € etc..

Is there a way that NumberFormat can add those automatically? or perhaps you can recommend a different solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get currency symbol by currency name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258511/how-to-get-currency-symbol-by-currency-name)

Comment: Hi, in this article they use a currency class http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the following library: [The Java Money and Currency API](https://javamoney.github.io/). it is an implementation of JSR 354: Java api for money and currency.

This is the code I have found that produces something close to desired requirements (example for Australian dollar: A$1.00):

```
    MonetaryAmount oneAuDDollar = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory()
        .setCurrency("AUD").setNumber(1).create();

    MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
        AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US)
            .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
            .set("pattern", "¤ #,##0.00###")
            .build());

    String formatted = format.format(oneAuDDollar);

    System.out.println(formatted);
```

output: `A$ 1.00`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numberformat-setcurrency-method-in-java-with-examples/) (First google search)

```
//JDK 11

NumberFormat nF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 

System.out.println("Initially Currency: " + nF.getCurrency().getSymbol()); 

nF.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.CANADA));

System.out.println("Currency set as: " + nF.getCurrency().getSymbol());
```

will print:

```
Initially Currency: $
Currency set as: CA$
```

For JDK 8 you need to **getSymbol()** with locale

```
//JDK 8

nF.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN));

System.out.println("Currency set as: " + nF.getCurrency().getSymbol(Locale.JAPAN));
```

will show sign as well

```
Currency set as: ￥
```

Comment: this is not an answer. maybe can pass as a comment

Comment: no, i know how to get the ***symbol***, i want the ***sign***

Comment: Take a look at this one. With `nF.getCurrency().getSymbol()`

Comment: @VSMent i still get CAD and not CA$ or C$

Comment: @guyshalev Hm.. works fine over [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/). I'll test it in IDE.

Comment: @guyshalev It was not working for me on JDK 8 as well. But on website mentioned earlier default JDK was 11. 
+ sign depends on locale. You can use `...getSymbol(Locale.XXX)` to check how will it look in other locales.

Comment: @guyshalev one more helpful website [here](https://coderanch.com/t/463940/java/show-countries-currency-symbols)